# cocoa/osx - Stop NSTextView from expanding past its frame dimension

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstextview

Does anyone know how to stop an NSTextView from expanding past the dimension of its frame when the text is added beyond those dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [textview setVerticallyResizable:NO] to do this.